# Javascript onblur/onfocus

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble with the two events, they work fine, however I have ran into a problem:
I have a div inside of a div. When the inner div is in focus, I want a set of style buttons to be appended to the outer div. However when i try to click on the buttons, it unfocuses the inner div and makes the buttons go away. I want them to go away when focus is lost but I dont want focus to be lost when I press a button. Sorry if this is a little confusing here is some code and a jsfiddle of it in action:

```
function addButtons() {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  var obj = document.getElementById('container');
  node.setAttribute('id', 'buttons');
  node.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="B" onClick="document.execCommand(\'bold\',false)" />';
  obj.appendChild(node); 
}

function removeButtons(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById('container');
  obj.removeChild(obj.childNodes[3]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnjGE/2/

If I remove the removeButtons() function, it works fine, but multiple buttons will be created.

I can try to clear things up, just ask.

Thankyou

Comment: `blur` fires before the `click`, so button is gone and won't register the click. Need to use different event to remove the button, like mouseleeave of DIV or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `return false;` statement on the `mousedown` event on the button, f.ex:

```
node.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onmousedown = function(e) {
    return false;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnjGE/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    if(e.target.id != 'buttons' && e.target.parentNode.id != 'buttons' && e.target.id != 'textarea'){
        removeButtons();
    }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnjGE/7/
Maybe this is a solution,but not perfect.